# React Native - NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: ios, reactjs, nsstring, react-native, nsnumber

Below is part of my react component.  I have a props named daysUntil coming into this component which contains a number.  In this example it is being pass the number 0 which results in the fontWeight function returning 700

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <Text style={this.style()}>
       {this.props.day}
      </Text>
    )
  },
  style: function() {
    return {
      fontWeight: this.fontWeight()
    }
  },
  fontWeight: function() {
    var weight = 7 - this.props.daysUntil;
    return weight * 100;
  }
```

I get the following error:

> JSON value '700' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSSTring.

I'm assuming this is because font-weight expects the value to be in string format.  What's the proper fix for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your fontWeight() function

```
return weight * 100;
```

maybe becomes:

```
var val= weight * 100;
return val.toString();
```

Comment: For me the issue was using a string for fontSize. like this: <Text style={{fontSize: '18'}}>words</Text>>. Should just be: fontSize: 18

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar problem, where I was passing in an icon instead of a uri to an Image. The code was written to accept `icon = 'path/to/icon'`:

```
<Image source={{ uri: icon }}>
```

but I was passing in `icon = require('path/to/icon')` and I had to switch the jsx to

```
<Image source={icon}>
```

Comment: I also had this issue. The problem was that I was using a `uri` as an actual imported asset, rather than just the URI itself. Very helpful

Answer (score 3):

fontWeight requires a string value and not an integer.

Just make sure you return a string:

```
return (weight * 100).toString();
```

Make also sure that your "weight" variable is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

in react font weight should be a string ,

in react doc they have specifically mention that
`fontWeight enum('normal', 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900')
Specifies font weight. The values 'normal' and 'bold' are supported for most fonts. Not all fonts have a variant for each of the numeric values, in that case the closest one is chosen.`

so you can choose like following

```
const boldText = {
  fontWeigth: '100'
}
```

or

```
const boldText = {
  fontWeight: 'bold'
}
```

in this code you can say

```
  style: function() {
    return {
      fontWeight: this.fontWeight()
    }
  },
  fontWeight: function() {
    var weight = 7 - this.props.daysUntil;
    return (weight * 100).toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StyleSheet` from `react-native` module, something like this:

```
import StyleSheet from 'react-native'

// declare the styles using Stylesheet.create
const myStyles = StyleSheet.create({marginTop:30})

//... some code inside render method

<Text style={myStyles}>
        This is an example
</Text>
```