# npx react-native-asset after upgrade to RN 0.71.x

Tags: react-native, npx

I keep getting this error when I start my metro bundler
JSON value 'N' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber after upgrade to the new RN 0.71.x
how can I get this npx react-native-asset run automatically

Comment: Just change your data type from NSString to NSNumber

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640369/react-native-nsnumber-cannot-be-converted-to-nsstring)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No. I scan the code, the only code snippet I can find with NSNumber is. ```- (void)testRendersWelcomeScreen
{
  UIViewController *vc = [[[RCTSharedApplication() delegate] window] rootViewController];
  NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:TIMEOUT_SECONDS];
  BOOL foundElement = NO;

  __block NSString *redboxError = nil;
#ifdef DEBUG
  RCTSetLogFunction(
      ^(RCTLogLevel level, RCTLogSource source, NSString *fileName, NSNumber *lineNumber, NSString *message) {
        if (level >= RCTLogLevelError) {
          redboxError = message;
        }
      });
#endif```

Comment: I replace NSNumber with NSString.   it does not help at all

Comment: here is a code snippet that I am not sure if this is pointing there ```const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  label: {
    color: 'black',
    marginVertical: 5,
    // height: 10,
  },
  input: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 50,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 80,
  },
});
```

Comment: I noticed in the jest unit test xx.test.js.snap there is this code ``` <Text
                    addBoxBackground={false}
                    borderRadius="N"```

Comment: why is the borderRadius become a string "N"?

Comment: Package.json:

"jest": "^29.2.1",
 "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
 "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",